# Ruby respond_to_missing? Call super or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Looking through the Rails codebase sometimes respond_to_missing? invokes super and sometimes not.  Are there cases where you should not invoke super from respond_to_missing?

Comment: Can you, perhaps, provide a few code snippets with both types of behaviour (with links to github, of course)?

Comment: eg. [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfb1e4dfd8813d3d5c75a15a750b3c53eebdea65/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb) calls super from respond_to? but also has [respond_to_missing?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfb1e4dfd8813d3d5c75a15a750b3c53eebdea65/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L503) which does not.  [StringInquirer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfb1e4dfd8813d3d5c75a15a750b3c53eebdea65/activesupport/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb) is more typical.

Comment: A common pattern is calling respond_to? on a wrapped object and skipping super, eg. [Duration#respond_to_missing?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfb1e4dfd8813d3d5c75a15a750b3c53eebdea65/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L365)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the class and the behavior you want out of `#respond_to_missing?`. Looking at `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, it is a proxy wrapper for `Time`. It tries to mimic it, fooling you into thinking it is an instance of `Time`. `TimeWithZone#is_a?` would respond `true` when passed `Time`, for example.

```
# Say we're a Time to thwart type checking.
def is_a?(klass)
  klass == ::Time || super
end
alias_method :kind_of?, :is_a?
```

`respond_to_missing?` should catch cases that would be caught by `method_missing`, so you have to look at both methods. `TimeWithZone#method_missing` delegates missing methods to `Time` instead of `super`.

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
  wrap_with_time_zone time.__send__(sym, *args, &block)
rescue NoMethodError => e
  raise e, e.message.sub(time.inspect, inspect), e.backtrace
end
```

So it makes sense that it would delegate `respond_to_missing?` to `Time` as well.

```
# Ensure proxy class responds to all methods that underlying time instance
# responds to.
def respond_to_missing?(sym, include_priv)
  return false if sym.to_sym == :acts_like_date?
  time.respond_to?(sym, include_priv)
end
```

Comment: Agreed.  Is the omission of `|| super` at the end of respond_to_missing? an oversight or a deliberate design decision?

Comment: @PiersC To me it looks like a deliberate design decision. They want it to return whatever `Time` would return. Same as how there is no `super` in `method_missing`, they just let `Time` figure out how to handle it. The consistent pattern in the class is that it is trying to trick the caller into thinking it is an instance of `Time`. As if the class is monkey patched without actually being altered at all.

Comment: @PiersC looking at your other example, `StringInquirer`, both `method_missing` and `respond_to_missing?` call `super`, and under the same conditions e.g. if `method_name[-1] != "?"`. It seems like a reasonable rule of thumb that in most cases `respond_to_missing?` should mirror `method_missing`.

Answer (score 2):

`respond_to_missing?` appears in Ruby version 1.9.2 as a solution to the `method` method. Here's a blog post by a Ruby core committer about it: http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/15/methodmissing-politely/

The reason for calling `super` however, is so that in the event your logic returns false, the call will bubble up the class hierarchy to `Object` which returns `false`. If your class is a subclass to a class that implements `respond_to_missing?` then you would want to call super in the event your logic returns false. This is generally an issue for library code and not so much for application code.

Comment: So you call super when you know a superclass also implements `respond_to_missing?`  Is it safe to call super if you are not sure?

Comment: Yes it is safe if you're not sure because it will just bubble up to the `Object` class